# I don't understand such a difference in the accuracy, please help

Tags: regression, deep-learning, tensorflow, keras, pandas

When I use a normalized values for the values of the target column in the following DL regression model I get a very good accuracy, and if I don't, the accuracy is a mess.

However I've reading that normalize the target values should not affect the behavior, so I'm confused and I don't understand what's going on in this case.

Can I please get a feedback about what I'm doing right or wrong?

I've paste the code below, nevertheless, for those of you that prefer an .ipynb view, you can visit the following:
https://github.com/Mike76b/Deep-Learning-Regression-model/blob/master/BkFriday-Demo.ipynb

And if you have troubles opening the .ipynb copy the link above and paste it in the following page:
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/

Thanks.

**Source of the data** (kaggle) 
https://www.kaggle.com/mehdidag/black-friday

**Modules used**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

...
```

Using TensorFlow backend.

*For explanatory purpose only:*

```
...

bkFriday_df = pd.read_csv('D:/ProgramData/Data Resources/BlackFriday/BlackFriday.csv', sep=',')

bkFriday_df.head()
User_ID     Product_ID  Gender  Age     Occupation  City_Category   Stay_In_Current_City_Years  Marital_Status  Product_Category_1  Product_Category_2  Product_Category_3  Purchase
0   1000001     P00069042   F   0-17    10  A   2   0   3   NaN     NaN     8370
1   1000001     P00248942   F   0-17    10  A   2   0   1   6.0     14.0    15200
2   1000001     P00087842   F   0-17    10  A   2   0   12  NaN     NaN     1422
3   1000001     P00085442   F   0-17    10  A   2   0   12  14.0    NaN     1057
4   1000002     P00285442   M   55+     16  C   4+  0   8   NaN     NaN     7969

bkFriday_df.shape
(537577, 12)

bkFriday_df.columns
Index(['User_ID', 'Product_ID', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Occupation', 'City_Category',
   'Stay_In_Current_City_Years', 'Marital_Status', 'Product_Category_1',
   'Product_Category_2', 'Product_Category_3', 'Purchase'],
  dtype='object')


bkFriday_df.describe(include = 'all')
    User_ID     Product_ID  Gender  Age     Occupation  City_Category   Stay_In_Current_City_Years  Marital_Status  Product_Category_1  Product_Category_2  Product_Category_3  Purchase
count   5.375770e+05    537577  537577  537577  537577.00000    537577  537577  537577.000000   537577.000000   370591.000000   164278.000000   537577.000000
unique  NaN     3623    2   7   NaN     3   5   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
top     NaN     P00265242   M   26-35   NaN     B   1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
freq    NaN     1858    405380  214690  NaN     226493  189192  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
mean    1.002992e+06    NaN     NaN     NaN     8.08271     NaN     NaN     0.408797    5.295546    9.842144    12.669840   9333.859853
std     1.714393e+03    NaN     NaN     NaN     6.52412     NaN     NaN     0.491612    3.750701    5.087259    4.124341    4981.022133
min     1.000001e+06    NaN     NaN     NaN     0.00000     NaN     NaN     0.000000    1.000000    2.000000    3.000000    185.000000
25%     1.001495e+06    NaN     NaN     NaN     2.00000     NaN     NaN     0.000000    1.000000    5.000000    9.000000    5866.000000
50%     1.003031e+06    NaN     NaN     NaN     7.00000     NaN     NaN     0.000000    5.000000    9.000000    14.000000   8062.000000
75%     1.004417e+06    NaN     NaN     NaN     14.00000    NaN     NaN     1.000000    8.000000    15.000000   16.000000   12073.000000
max     1.006040e+06    NaN     NaN     NaN     20.00000    NaN     NaN     1.000000    18.000000   18.000000   18.000000   23961.000000

...
```

**Columns that I will use to build the model**

```
...

Some of them
toAdd_df = pd.get_dummies(bkFriday_df[['Gender', 'Age', 'City_Category', 'Stay_In_Current_City_Years']])
toAdd_df.shape
(537577, 17)

Predictors DataFrame
All of them
pred_df = bkFriday_df[['Occupation', 'Marital_Status']].join(toAdd_df)
pred_df.shape
(537577, 19)

pred_df.head()
    Occupation  Marital_Status  Gender_F    Gender_M    Age_0-17    Age_18-25   Age_26-35   Age_36-45   Age_46-50   Age_51-55   Age_55+     City_Category_A     City_Category_B     City_Category_C     Stay_In_Current_City_Years_0    Stay_In_Current_City_Years_1    Stay_In_Current_City_Years_2    Stay_In_Current_City_Years_3    Stay_In_Current_City_Years_4+
0   10  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   10  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
2   10  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   10  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
4   16  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1

pred_df.isnull().any()
Occupation                       False
Marital_Status                   False
Gender_F                         False
Gender_M                         False
Age_0-17                         False
Age_18-25                        False
Age_26-35                        False
Age_36-45                        False
Age_46-50                        False
Age_51-55                        False
Age_55+                          False
City_Category_A                  False
City_Category_B                  False
City_Category_C                  False
Stay_In_Current_City_Years_0     False
Stay_In_Current_City_Years_1     False
Stay_In_Current_City_Years_2     False
Stay_In_Current_City_Years_3     False
Stay_In_Current_City_Years_4+    False
dtype: bool


#Normalizing Occupation column
pred_df['Occupation'] = pred_df['Occupation']/pred_df['Occupation'].max()

...
```

### Here is where the code of the model/questions begin

**Purchase (target) column info**

MIN val: 185

MAX val: 23961

MEAN val: 9333.859

STD val: 4921.022

```
...

#Normalizing Purchase (target) column
targ_df = bkFriday_df['Purchase']/bkFriday_df['Purchase'].max()


targ_df.head()

0    0.349318
1    0.634364
2    0.059346
3    0.044113
4    0.332582
Name: Purchase, dtype: float64

targ_df.shape
(537577,)

targ_df.isnull().any()
False


#Define classification model

def regression_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(19,)))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    # compile model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model


# build the model
model = regression_model()


#Using a normalized target

model.fit(pred_df, targ_df, validation_split=0.3, epochs=10, verbose=2)

Train on 376303 samples, validate on 161274 samples
Epoch 1/10
 - 8s - loss: 597019.1829 - val_loss: 2.6506
Epoch 2/10
 - 8s - loss: 0.6978 - val_loss: 0.0456
Epoch 3/10
 - 8s - loss: 0.0436 - val_loss: 0.0434
Epoch 4/10
 - 8s - loss: 0.0433 - val_loss: 0.0431
Epoch 5/10
 - 7s - loss: 0.0430 - val_loss: 0.0430
Epoch 6/10
 - 8s - loss: 0.0429 - val_loss: 0.0431
Epoch 7/10
 - 8s - loss: 0.0428 - val_loss: 0.0430
Epoch 8/10
 - 8s - loss: 0.0427 - val_loss: 0.0428
Epoch 9/10
 - 8s - loss: 0.0426 - val_loss: 0.0431
Epoch 10/10
 - 8s - loss: 0.0426 - val_loss: 0.0428

<keras.callbacks.History at 0x2d64e63d4e0>


#Using a target that is NOT normalized

targ_df1 = bkFriday_df['Purchase']

model.fit(pred_df, targ_df1, validation_split=0.3, epochs=10, verbose=2)

Train on 376303 samples, validate on 161274 samples
Epoch 1/10
 - 10s - loss: 27449712.1709 - val_loss: 24691241.0429
Epoch 2/10
 - 9s - loss: 24545862.6251 - val_loss: 24694663.1769
Epoch 3/10
 - 9s - loss: 24547027.7592 - val_loss: 24691479.8413
Epoch 4/10
 - 9s - loss: 24549062.7868 - val_loss: 24693882.1764
Epoch 5/10
 - 9s - loss: 24546786.5014 - val_loss: 24694371.9963
Epoch 6/10
 - 9s - loss: 24548953.5945 - val_loss: 24693229.1358
Epoch 7/10
 - 9s - loss: 24546170.8858 - val_loss: 24692611.7169
Epoch 8/10
 - 9s - loss: 24547501.0794 - val_loss: 24700711.9410
Epoch 9/10
 - 9s - loss: 24548278.9858 - val_loss: 24690487.4462
Epoch 10/10
 - 9s - loss: 24548030.6103 - val_loss: 24702105.0564

<keras.callbacks.History at 0x2d64c66ff60>

targ_df1.dtype
dtype('int64')

#end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are trying to evaluating a **regression** problem with a **classification** metric (i.e. accuracy).

Accuracy tells you how many predictions you got right as a percentage of your total predictions. For example if your model makes $10$ predictions and gets $7$ of them right, you have a $70\%$ accuracy.

In regression problems, you are trying to predict a continuous value, in this case the amount of the purchase in dollars. For this you need a metric suitable for regression. These metrics show you **how close** you are to the target price. For example, if the target price is $9.99$ and your model predicts $10.50$ it's better than if it predicted $11.34$. If you used accuracy both of these two predictions would be counted as *misses* and we'd have no information over which one is better. For this reason we need a regression metric, e.g. [Mean Absolute Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error), [Mean Squared Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), etc.

**TL;DR: Don't use accuracy to evaluate regression models!**

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I thought that I was evaluating the model with the Mean Squared Error when I set `loss='mean_squared_error'` now I changed that line of code to `model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics = ['mean_squared_error'])` Is it all I had to do? and if so, could you please tell me how can I see the performance now? I mean, after running the model, what function/line of code should I use to see how well it was with the new setting. I know it might be too simple questions but is just that I'm starting to learn all these concepts and tools. Thanks rgds

Comment: The performance of your model can be measured through the MSE on the validation/test set. A *lower* MSE means a *better* model (because the predictions fall closer to their actual values).